# Repeat a 2D NumPy array N times

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to augment(replicate) a 2d array of shape 32X32 to a 3d array of shape 32X32X3 by duplicating the source array. How can i do this in the best possible way?

Below is the sample of the source and expected array. I need to apply this logic over a bigger scope of my application

Source array:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Expected array:

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]]])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By my tests, `np.repeat` is a little faster than `np.tile`:

```
X = np.repeat(arr[None,:], 3, axis=0)
```

Alternatively, use `np.concatenate`:

```
X = np.concatenate([[arr]] * 3, axis=0)
```

---

```
arr = np.arange(10000 * 1000).reshape(10000, 1000)

%timeit np.repeat(arr[None,:], 3, axis=0)
%timeit np.tile(arr, (3, 1, 1))
%timeit np.concatenate([[arr]] * 3, axis=0)
# Read-only, array cannot be modified.
%timeit np.broadcast_to(arr, (3, *arr.shape))
# Creating copy of the above.
%timeit np.broadcast_to(arr, (3, *arr.shape)).copy()

170 ms ± 3.82 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
187 ms ± 3.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
243 ms ± 3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
10.9 µs ± 218 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops 
189 ms ± 2.45 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)each)
```

```
np.array_equals(np.repeat(arr[None,:], 3, axis=0), 
                np.tile(arr, (3, 1, 1))
True
```

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark. Looks like `tile` source itself calls `repeat`.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a job for `np.tile`:

```
In [101]: np.tile(A, (3,1,1))
Out[101]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]]])
```

The second argument specifies the number of copies on each dimension.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to modify the result, make use of `broadcast_to`:

```
np.broadcast_to(arr, (3, *arr.shape))
```

---

Validation using @coldspeed's answer:

```
arr = np.arange(10000 * 1000).reshape(10000, 1000)
X = np.repeat(arr[None,:], 3, axis=0)
broadcast_x = np.broadcast_to(arr, (3, *arr.shape))

np.array_equal(X, broadcast_x)
```

```
True
```

---

If you *do* need to be able to modify, you can call `copy()` on the result, which should come close to `repeat` and `tile` in terms of speed.